# jQuery Validate docx

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I tried to use jQuery [Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to validate a .docx file upload.

```
$("#my_form").validate({
  rules: {
    upload1: { required: true, accept: "docx"},
    upload2: { required: true, accept: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"},
  }
);
```

However, both rules do not work.  What should be the value for the property *accept*?

Comment: Do you test in a browser with the HTML5 file API available?

Comment: @Boldewyn, I tested the script with Chrome version 24.0.1312.57 m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing extension of a file you need to use the rule `extension` as mentioned in the [documentation here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/extension#extension).

Ex:

```
$('#commentForm').validate({
    rules: {
        file: {
            required: true,
            extension: 'docx'
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QkATu/1/)